# How to figure out if an email is answered using Exchange EWS API?

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to figure out if there is an "ANSWERED" flag which could be used to determine if the Email has been answered using EWS API. Does anyone know a way to get that information?

Thanks
Naresh

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the notification which Outlook displays on a mail ("You replied to this message on xx.xx.xxxx"), you can retrieve this info by reading the PidTagLastVerbExecuted PidTagLastVerbExecutionTime properties from an item. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433482(v=EXCHG.80).aspx, section 2.2.1.14 and .15. The property definitions can be found in the master property list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Can you do this via the EWS API though?

Comment: Yes - you can do this by Setting Extended properties on the Exchange item.